# upload a sample pyspark dataframe to Azure blob, after converting it to excel format

Tags: pandas, pyspark, azure-databricks, pyspark-pandas

I'm trying to upload a sample pyspark dataframe to Azure blob, after converting it to excel format. Getting the below error. Also, below is the snippet of my sample code.

If there is a other way to do the same, pls let me know.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

import pandas as ps
#%pip install xlwt
#%pip install openpyxl
#%pip install fsspec

my_data = [
            ("A","1","M",3000),
            ("B","2","F",4000),
            ("C","3","M",4000)
          ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=my_data,schema=schema)

pandasDF = df.toPandas()

pandasDF.to_excel("wasbs://blob.paybledvclient1@civblbstr.blob.core.windows.net/output_file.xlsx")
```

ValueError: Protocol not known: wasbs

Answer (score 1):

You are directly using python library `pandas` to write the data. This isn't work this way. You need to first mount the Azure Blob storage container and then write the data.

To mount, use following command:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = {"<conf-key>":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})
```

To write, use below commands:

```
df.write
 .mode("overwrite")
 .option("header", "true")
 .csv("dbfs:/mnt/azurestorage/filename.csv"))
```

Comment: Could you please help me to make some column as read-only (let's say Salary column ) while writing to excel format?